# horizontal align card using map function ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to align horizontal card using grid with react-bootstrap and map function

I'm using redux to bring the Data through the props so I create a JSON to traverse it with a function Map

this is a fraction of my code

```
 render() {
    //const { tablaCliente } = this.state
    //const { isLoading } = this.state
    const { entity } = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Header></Header>
            <div className="col-xs-4">
                <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/newclient">Nuevo Cliente</a>
            </div>
            <br />
            <center>
                <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
                    <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                </Spinner>
            </center>
            <Container>
                {entity && entity.getAllEntities && entity.getAllEntities.length > 0 && entity.getAllEntities.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <CardGroup value={item}key={index}>
                            <Card style={{ width: '1rem' }} >
                                <Card.Img variant="top" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22286%22%20height%3D%22180%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20286%20180%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_16b0e6bd8ef%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23999%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_16b0e6bd8ef%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22286%22%20height%3D%22180%22%20fill%3D%22%23373940%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22107.203125%22%20y%3D%2296.3%22%3E286x180%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" />
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title> Cliente {item.name}</Card.Title>
                                    <Card.Text>
                                        {item.description}
                                    </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                                <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
                                    <ListGroupItem>Estado:{''}{JSON.stringify(item.state)}</ListGroupItem>
                                    <ListGroupItem>Creado por: {item.createby}</ListGroupItem>
                                </ListGroup>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Link href="/cliente">Card Link</Card.Link>
                                    <Card.Link href="/cliente">Editar</Card.Link>
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Card>
                        </CardGroup>)
                })}
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont use react-bootstrap but u can achieve it by doing

```html
<Container>
  <div class='row'>
  {this.map(value => {
    return (
      <div class='col-md-6'>
        <Card />
      </div>
    )
  });}
  </div>
</Container>
```

This should work

Wrap the map function in **row** and the returning jsx in **col**

And dont just write a whole logic in jsx use functions or components